# What to do to make built-in construction converge the true mean just like arima.sim's successful convergence?

Tags: r, apply, simulation, arima

(Reproducible code added). I am simulating the AR(1) process $$ y_t=1+0.6y_{t-1} + \nu_t \ \ \ \nu_t \sim N(0,1) $$

Mean is (by taking the expectaion of both sides): m=1+0.6m; m=2.5.

I think the following must give very very approximate mean values, but they don't!

Built-in construction:

```
N <- 500; ro <- 0.6; a <- 1
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm(N,0,1))
y <- as.data.frame(rep(0,N))
y <- unlist(apply(as.matrix(2:N), 1, function(t) { y[t,] <- a + ro*y[t-1,] + v[t] }))
# mean(y) = 1,023945
```

The simulation via `arima.sim`:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.6), n=500, mean=0, sd=sqrt(1)) + 2.5
# mean(y)=2.527922
```

Why are the means so different?
What to do to correct the built-in construction?

**What I did:**
I tried "a" to be "1, 10, 100" one by one in the built-in construction.
The mean and variance in each case are "m=1.023945, v=1.025207", "m=10.02394, v=1.025207", "m=100.0239, v=1.025207" respectively.

So, mean appears to be "a + 0.0239" instead of the true values that are 1/0.4=2.5; 10/0.4=25; 100/0.4=250 respectively.